# Why there is variation in answer while using multiple threads to count word frequencies of a large file?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

My objective is to count the frequencies of each word while reading a large file using multiple threads.
I am implementing Runnable interface to achieve multi-threading. But while executing the program I'm not getting the correct answer every time. Sometimes, it is giving correct output and sometimes not. But using Callable interface instead of Runnable, the program executes correctly without any error.

This is the main class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WordFrequencyRunnableTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String filePath = "C:/Users/Mukesh Kumar/Desktop/data.txt";
        WordFrequencyRunnableTest runnableTest = new WordFrequencyRunnableTest();
        Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = runnableTest.parseLines(filePath);
        runnableTest.printResult(wordFrequencies);
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Total execution time in millis: " + elapsedTime);
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> parseLines(String filePath) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String eachLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (eachLine != null) {
                List<String> linesForEachThread = new ArrayList<>();
                while (linesForEachThread.size() != 100 && eachLine != null) {
                    linesForEachThread.add(eachLine);
                    eachLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                WordFrequencyUsingRunnable task = new WordFrequencyUsingRunnable(linesForEachThread, wordFrequencies);
                Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        return wordFrequencies;
    }

    public void printResult(Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies) {
        wordFrequencies.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
    }
}
```

And this is the logic class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WordFrequencyUsingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final List<String> linesForEachThread;
    private final Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies;

    public WordFrequencyUsingRunnable(List<String> linesForEachThread, Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies) {
        this.linesForEachThread = linesForEachThread;
        this.wordFrequencies = wordFrequencies;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<String> currentThreadLines = new ArrayList<>(linesForEachThread);
        for (String eachLine : currentThreadLines) {
            String[] eachLineWords = eachLine.toLowerCase().split("([,.\\s]+)");
            synchronized (wordFrequencies) {
                for (String eachWord : eachLineWords) {
                    if (wordFrequencies.containsKey(eachWord)) {
                        wordFrequencies.replace(eachWord, wordFrequencies.get(eachWord) + 1);
                    }
                    wordFrequencies.putIfAbsent(eachWord, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am hoping for good responses and thanking in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for all threads to close before printing the results.

```java
public class WordFrequencyRunnableTest {

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ...
        ...
        Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = runnableTest.parseLines(filePath);
        for(Thread thread: threads)
        {
           thread.join();
        }
        runnableTest.printResult(wordFrequencies);
        ...
        ...
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> parseLines(String filePath) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String eachLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (eachLine != null) {
                List<String> linesForEachThread = new ArrayList<>();
                while (linesForEachThread.size() != 100 && eachLine != null) {
                    linesForEachThread.add(eachLine);
                    eachLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                WordFrequencyUsingRunnable task = new WordFrequencyUsingRunnable(linesForEachThread, wordFrequencies);
                Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                thread.start();
                threads.add(thread); // Add thread to the list.
            }
        }
        return wordFrequencies;
    }
}
```

PS - You can use `ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>` to avoid having to synchronize access to the hashmap. The program will run faster that way.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning ForkJoinPool as an alternative solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now, the problem is solved and is working fine.